# Dynamic routing in Angular

Tags: angularjs, templates

I have an Angular app which is supposed to display different pages depending on the resource in the following way:

1. Given url: localhost/foo/456
2. Call REST service (fooService) to get a descriptor for the foo.
3. Based on the descriptor use an appropriate template.

Here's the config part (a bit of a pseudocode):

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'fooService', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, fooService) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode();
    var fooTemplateUrlSelector = function (routeParams) {
            var foo = fooService.getFoo(routeParams.fooId);
            switch (foo.TemplateId) {
            case 1:
                return 'Foo1.html';
            case 2:
                return 'Foo2.html';
            default:
                return 'Unsupported.html';
            }
        };

    $routeProvider.when('/foo/:fooId', { templateUrl: fooTemplateUrlSelector, controller: 'FooController' })
```

The problem is that in the config phase I don't have access to any service ('Unknown provider: fooService').
It seems to be an Angular constraint that in the config part you're allowed to only access 'static' things. I get it.

What's the best (in terms of best practices) solution to this problem?

The templates might differ a lot, so I don't want to have one html file with a lot of "if TemplateId == 1, then display_some_markup else if TemplateId == 2 then display_something_else".

Comment: you could make `provider` instead of making `service` which would be easily available in config phase

Comment: How is my provider supposed to have $http injected in order to make a REST call? Can you give me a link to an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is must be in app.config() ?
I preffer this way:

html:

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-init="init()">
    <div ng-if="foo.templateID == 1">
      // ng-include="foo1.html"
    </div>
    <div ng-if="foo.templateID == 1">
      // ng-include="foo2.html"
    </div>
</div>
```

---

controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope, fooService) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.foo = fooService.getFoo(routeParams.fooId);
    };
    // other functions and features
};
```